# set value in C++/CX e.g. Box<Color>

Tags: c++-cx, boxing

When I was setting the background colour of the TitleBar, I used ref new Color( ) because it is a Color^, but Color has no constructors to set the red colour. So I'm trying to change the R Field value of the BackgroundColor of the TitleBar directly, but it doesn't work.

I solved the problem with ColorHelper, or as Raymond Chen suggested, by treating Color as a regular variable and not boxing it. But I'm still not sure if I can't change the value of the variable once it is already Box.

```
    // change title bar color
    using Windows::UI::ColorHelper;
    using Windows::UI::Color;
    auto bar = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView()->TitleBar;
    
    // no constrctor(int a,int r,int g,int b)
    // bar->BackgroundColor = ref new Color(255, 255, 0, 0);
    
    // error:
    // bar->BackgroundColor->Value.R = 255;

    // okay:
    bar->BackgroundColor = ColorHelper::FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);

    // okay:
    Color color;
    color.R = 255; color.A = 255; color.G = 255; color.B = 0;
    bar->BackgroundColor = color; // Color can set to Color^ (implicit)
```

Error:

```
using namespace Windows::UI;
Color^ color = ref new Color();
// error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
color->Value.R = 255;
```

R is writable:
[MSDN Color Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.color?view=winrt-22621)

although code can run (below)

```
Color color2;
color2.R = 255;
```

but I still don't know how to set boxing value.

The Codes I already Try:

```
auto color = ref new Color();

// can't casting from Color* to Color
auto r2 = safe_cast<Color>(color); 
auto auto r3 = (Color)color;

// __this is not a member of Color 
// Value is not a member of Color
auto r4 = (Color)color->Value;

// can run, but color doesn't change
auto r5 = (Color)*color;
r5.B = 255;
auto& r6 = (Color)*color;
r6.B = 255;
```

Maybe someone can clear up my confusion.

Comment: `Color` is a struct, not a class. You don't need to allocate it on the heap. Just declare it as a regular variable

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand a little bit about boxing is for manged memory in the process of searching for answers.

I even read "Don't boxing variables if not necessary as it will cause a loss of efficiency".

Because I had a similar problem when I tried to change the MinDetectableFaceSize when using Windows::Media::FaceAnalysis::FaceDetector. I gave up at that time, but I did not expect to encounter similar problems again. It is the official MSDN "this variable is settable", but in fact I can not successfully set.

Comment: Not sure how boxing entered the discussion. `Color color; color.R = value;` don't say `new`. There is no reason to box the value in your examples.

Comment: thank you, @RaymondChen as your suggestion, I declare it as a regular variable and set to a color^ variable, it's work. 

And, I change FaceDetector::MinDetectableFaceSize which is the problem I was having before.

Comment: Boxed values are immutable. Notice that [there is a read-only Value property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/platform-ibox-interface?view=msvc-170). If you want to change the value, you'll have to create a new box.